# Unable to print items from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, printing, superglobals

My code is supposed to fix the name of the courses by capitalizing the first letter of each word. Then I need to sort them in the globals array and print out a message with them. I think I have done all of that correctly but when I try to even print out just the variable I get nothing in my browser and no error messages to go off either. I'm wondering how I can print these changed variables in the array.

```
<?php
$course1 = "advanced web development";
$course2 = "mobile app development";
$course3 = "info systems with business intell";

function fixCourseName($courseName)
{
$courseName = ucwords($courseName);
return $courseName;
}

$GLOBALS['CIS475'] = fixCourseName ($course1);
$GLOBALS['CIS360'] = fixCourseName ($course2);
$GLOBALS['CIS429'] = fixCourseName ($course3);

print_r $GLOBALS['CIS475'];

?>
```

Comment: vote to close as typo

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
$course1 = "advanced web development";
$course2 = "mobile app development";
$course3 = "info systems with business intell";

function fixCourseName($courseName)
{
$courseName = ucwords($courseName);
return $courseName;
}

$GLOBALS['CIS475'] = fixCourseName ($course1);
$GLOBALS['CIS360'] = fixCourseName ($course2);
$GLOBALS['CIS429'] = fixCourseName ($course3);

print_r($GLOBALS['CIS475']);

?>
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanations?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error -- **[`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)** is a function; you want to pass `$GLOBALS['CIS475']` as the argument.

Replace `print_r $GLOBALS['CIS475']` with `print_r($GLOBALS['CIS475'])` and your code will work as expected.

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/Sk0Xn)**.